# displaying the ridge orientation as a flow chart

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, fingerprint, image-segmentation

I am trying to view my local ridge orientation of a fingerprint as a flowchart. But I seem to fail miserably at doing so. My method consists of the following steps:

- use the `lro` function
- find the most dominant angle in a 16x16 block
- create a line segment and rotate it by the dominant angle to display it

The problem is that while the angles that the `lro` produces are good, the display of these in the flowchart does not work at all. There I just get a lot of random angles going in all kind of directions. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
def lro(im_np):
    eps = 2**(-52)
    orientsmoothsigma = 4

#     original
    Gxx = cv2.Sobel(im_np, -1, 2, 0)
    Gxy = cv2.Sobel(im_np, -1, 1, 1)
    Gyy = cv2.Sobel(im_np, -1, 0, 2)



    Gxx = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(Gxx, orientsmoothsigma)
    Gxy = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(Gxy, orientsmoothsigma)
    Gyy = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(Gyy, orientsmoothsigma)

    angle = math.pi/2. + numpy.divide(numpy.arctan2(numpy.multiply(Gxy,2), numpy.subtract(Gxx,Gyy)),2)

    return angle

def createLine(im_np):

    #Assumes it is 17x17
    #Takes in the block-direction
    #returns a block-direction image as a numpy array

    angle = numpy.max(im_np)
#     print im_np.shape
    im = Image.new('L', (im_np.shape[0], im_np.shape[1]), (0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 
    draw.line([(0,im_np.shape[0]/2), (im_np.shape[0],im_np.shape[0]/2)], fill=255)
    im = im.rotate(angle)
    img_np2 = numpy.asarray(im)
#     print img_np2
    return img_np2

def findDomAngle(im_np):
    mask = numpy.zeros((180,2))

    for i in range(180):
        mask[i][0] = i+1

    for i in range(im_np.shape[0]):
        for j in range(im_np.shape[0]):
            mask[im_np[i][j]-1][1] +=  1

    max = 0
    bestdir = 0
    for i in range(180):
        if mask[i][1] > max:
            bestdir = i + 1 
            max = mask[i][1]
#     print mask
#     print max
    return bestdir


def blkdir(angle_mat):
    x = angle_mat.shape[0]
    y = angle_mat.shape[1]
#     print angle_mat

    domAngle = findDomAngle(angle_mat)
#     print domAngle
    blkAngle = angle_mat
    blkAngle.setflags(write=True)

    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            blkAngle[i][j] = domAngle

    return blkAngle
```

I am applying another function to process the `image` block by block, but this method has proven to work so I don't find it relevant to include.